# window.addEventListener is not invoked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can you please help me understand where the code is wrong. The below code doesn't invoke the event handler for `window.onload` event:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Example</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         window.addEventListener("onload", onLoad)
         
             function onLoad(e)
             {
                debugger;
                console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e));
             }
      </script>             
   </head>
   <body> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's no event named "onload", it's "load".

Comment: Teemu is correct. In the context of addEventListener, you don't use the "on..." prefix. Just "load" or "click"

Comment: Very true, `window` has `onload` property, but the event model has `load` event.

Comment: Yes. Teemu is right.

Comment: [Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
window.onload = function(e) {
    debugger;
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e));
};
```

Comment: I was trying to add event handlers using addEventHandler method instead. As Teemu stated, I can just use "load" instead of "onload" and my code works.

Comment: Ok, that just seemed like a long way to do it, since onload only happens once. I think EventHandlers are better experimented with by using buttons and such